# Alternative offline upgrade method

Tags: 11.04, 11.10, upgrade

How can I upgrade to Ubuntu 11.10 from 11.04 other than *online*?
Thanks for your reply. I have downloaded the iso file but when i run the cdromupgrade script and selected the option not to use t he internet connection .But after some time the upgrade fails stating that no internet connection ,fail to fetch files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any access to the internet, I don't believe there is any way to upgrade. You'll need a copy of installation media and it's not really available in stores. If you can get a friend with internet access to get a copy of the iso, they rip a CD for you or create a USB install.

Answer (score 3):

**Upgrading Using the Alternate CD/DVD**

Download the alternate installation CD from http://releases.ubuntu.com/oneiric/

```
sudo mkdir -p /media/cdrom
sudo mount -o loop ~/Desktop/ubuntu-11.10-alternate-i386.iso /media/cdrom
```

A dialog will be displayed offering you the opportunity to upgrade using that CD.
Follow the on-screen instructions.

If the upgrade dialog is not displayed for any reason, you may also run the following command using Alt+F2:

```
gksu "sh /media/cdrom/cdromupgrade"
```

Source : [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OneiricUpgrades#Upgrading_Using_the_Alternate_CD.2BAC8-DVD)

Comment: I have downloaded the iso file but when i run the cdromupgrade script and selected the option not to use t he internet connection .But after some time the upgrade fails stating that no internet connection ,fail to fetch files

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Alternate](http://releases.ubuntu.com/11.10/) cd iso to upgrade without network access